# Apache camel route, activemq and mybatis - passing argument

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, mybatis

assume that I have route like this.

```
        <route>
            <from uri="activemq:queue:someQueue"/>
            <to uri="mybatis:select-items?statementType=SelectOne"/>
        </route>
```

How can I get messaeg from activemq and pass it into mybatis select? (It's just a string)

@Edit.

I want to get string like this: `category1, category2`

and my select looks like:

```
<select id="select-authors" resultMap="authors-result">
                SELECT
                 name, age, category
                FROM author
                WHERE category IN
                <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="categories"
                 open="(" separator="," close=")">
                    #{item}
                 </foreach>
     </select>
```

result map just mapping these 3 fields.

Comment: Update please your question with more details. What message was send to someQueue ? How your mapping looks like for select-items query ?

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a string like "category1, category2" from activemq consumer you need to make collection from it for mybatis foreach processing. I make example using java dsl cause it would be faster.

```
from("activemq:queue:someQueue")
            .process(exchange -> {
                String jmsString = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(jmsString.split(","));
                exchange.getIn().setBody(strings);
            })
            .to("mybatis:select-items?statementType=SelectOne");
```

And change mapping like :

```
<select id="select-authors" parameterType="java.util.List" resultMap="authors-result">
            SELECT
             name, age, category
            FROM author
            WHERE category IN
            <foreach item="item" collection="list"
             open="(" separator="," close=")">
                #{item}
             </foreach>
 </select>
```

This should work. More useful examples you can find [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-mybatis/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/mybatis)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Camel simple language (http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) to access the content (body or properties) of the JMS message:

```
<route>
   <from uri="activemq:queue:someQueue"/>
   <to uri="mybatis:select-items?statementType=${body}"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Why are you setting body object to statementType parameter ? According documentation it is need to be StatementType enum value.

Comment: Sorry, I apparently misunderstood the question. It thought it was about how to pass the JMS message (body) as argument/parameter of a target uri...